# How to update product quantity after adding product to cart?

Tags: django, angular6

I am working on a shopping cart project which is developed using angular and `django`. I want to update the qty of product when adding a product. but now the qty is updated when page is refreshed.

Below code i have been tried so far.

**Home.Component.ts:**

```
    async ngOnInit() {
    await this.getUpdatedCart();}

    ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();}

     async getUpdatedCart() {
      await this.cartService.getCart(this.products);
      this.subscription =  this.cartService.updatedCart
      .subscribe(cart => {
       this.cart = cart;
       console.log('cart', this.cart);
     });
  }
```

**shopping-cart.services.ts:**

```
   updatedCart = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');

    async getCart(product) {
    const cartId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartId'));
    if (cartId) {
       this.http.get(this.globalService.baseUrl + 'shopping-cart/' + cartId + '/').subscribe(data => this.updatedCart.next(data));
    }}
```

**product-card.component.ts:**

```
     export class ProductCardComponent {
     @Input('product') product;
     @Input('shopping-cart') shoppingCart;

     constructor(private cartService: ShoppingCartService,
              private homeComponent: HomeComponent) {
    }

    async addToCart(product) {
    await this.cartService.addProductToCart(product);
    await this.homeComponent.getUpdatedCart();
  }

    getQuantity() {
     if (!this.shoppingCart) {
      return 0;
     }
     const item = this.shoppingCart.carts;
     for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
      if (item[i].product === this.product.id) {
        return item[i].qty;
      }
    }
    return 0;}}
```

**product-card.component.html:**

```
  <div class="card-footer">
   <button (click)="addToCart(product) " class="btn btn-primary btn- 
    block">Add to cart</button>
       <div>{{getQuantity() }}</div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

I want when user click "add to cart" button then the quantity will be updated.
but quantity is updated after i click the button twice.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Subjects** ([Example](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/25/angular-6-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject)) in this case. Make a service in *shopping-cart.services.ts* and fetch cart data from there. You will get the updated cart on subscription of that cart.

Comment: As you suggested I have updated my code. but still no change. I think i am doing  mistake somewhere @Aarti

Comment: You can also use **ngDoCheck** life cycle of Angular and check cart variable in that. Although, this approach is not recommendable because it will check every event change. But in your case, It might work.